# how can I change the date picker value when opening another modal?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have one modal and use it for creating and editing my records, the problem is that when click create and select a date then close it and then I click edit and select a date the selected value is from my create modal not my edit modal. I tried using `datepicker('update')` and `datepicker('clearDates')`. but it wouldn't work.

Add and Edit Buttons:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="{{ $data-}}" data-toggle="tooltip" onClick="editFunc('{{ $data->id }}')" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-success">Edit</a>

<a class="btn btn-info" onClick="add()" href="javascript:void(0)"> Create</a>
```

here is my script:

```
function add() {
  $('#fromDate').val('{{ date("Y-m-d", strtotime(today())) }}');
  $('#toDate').val('{{ date("Y-m-d", strtotime(today())) }}');
  dateToDate();
}
function editFunc(id) {
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "{{ url('edit') }}",
  data: { id: id },
  success: function(res){
   //Populates input fromdate and todate
   $('#fromDate').val(res.FromDate); 
   $('#toDate').val(res.ToDate);
   dateToDate();
  }
 });
}
function dateToDate() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            function calculate() {
                var d1 = $('#fromDate').datepicker('getDate');
                var d2 = $('#toDate').datepicker('getDate');
                var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                var diff = 0;
                if (d1 && d2) {
                    diff = Math.round(Math.abs((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (oneDay))) + 1;
                }
                $('#duration').val(diff);
            }
            $('#fromDate').datepicker({
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                autoclose: true,
                startDate: new Date()
            }).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
                var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
                $('#toDate').datepicker('setStartDate', minDate);
                calculate();
            });
            $('#toDate').datepicker({
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                autoclose: true,
                startDate: new Date()
            }).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
                var minDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
                $('#fromDate').datepicker('setEndDate', minDate);
                calculate();

            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `$('#fromDate').datepicker('setEndDate', minDate);` I tried adding two parameters to the function `dateToDate()` which is **toDate** and **fromDate** and replace the **minDate**. also changed on how I set the values when clicking the **Create** ang **Edit** buttons. Check the code below. If you have a better way of this please let me know. Thanks!

```
function add() {
      $('#fromDate').val('{{ date("Y-m-d", strtotime(today())) }}');
      $('#toDate').val('{{ date("Y-m-d", strtotime(today())) }}');
      var todate = $('#toDate').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    }).datepicker('setDate','{{ date("Y-m-d", strtotime(today())) }}'),
    fromdate = $('#fromDate').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    }).datepicker('setDate','{{ date("Y-m-d", strtotime(today())) }}');
    dateToDate(todate,fromdate);
    }
    function editFunc(id) {
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{{ url('edit') }}",
      data: { id: id },
      success: function(res){
       //Populates input fromdate and todate
       $('#fromDate').val(res.FromDate); 
       $('#toDate').val(res.ToDate);
       var todate = $('#toDate').datepicker({
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            }).datepicker('setDate',res.ToDate),
            fromdate = $('#fromDate').datepicker({
                format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
            }).datepicker('setDate',res.FromDate);
      dateToDate(todate,fromdate);
      }
     });
    }
    function dateToDate(toDate,fromDate) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function calculate() {
                    var d1 = $('#fromDate').datepicker('getDate');
                    var d2 = $('#toDate').datepicker('getDate');
                    var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                    var diff = 0;
                    if (d1 && d2) {
                        diff = Math.round(Math.abs((d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (oneDay))) + 1;
                    }
                    $('#duration').val(diff);
                }
        $('#fromDate').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            autoclose: true,
        }).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
            toDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
            $('#toDate').datepicker('setStartDate', toDate);
            calculate();
        });
        $('#toDate').datepicker({
            format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
            autoclose: true,
        }).on('changeDate', function(selected) {
            fromDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
            $('#fromDate').datepicker('setEndDate', fromDate);

            calculate();
        });
  });
}
```